# PHP - start_session undefined

Tags: php, session

I've been using session_start() fine with my other PHP files. Now however, I am trying to put functions into one file and then be able to call them from various other PHP files.

I simply have this in one file:

```
    <?php require("CustomerFunctions.php");
        start_session();
        PrintCustomerTable();
    ?>
```

However I am getting  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function start_session()`

Again, I am able to use start_session everywhere else in my files but now for some reason it won't work in this file. It has the same result even if I remove the `require`.

Comment: what is `start_session();`? Do you have this function declared already?

Answer (score 6):

The function you're looking for is called [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start).

Comment: He might have it declared in `CustomerFunctions.php` though.

Comment: @edvinas.me: If so, he'd know where it exists and what to include.  :P  And since he's already including it, and isn't getting any error but that one...that's probably not the problem.